# How hard is it to display a colored rectangle in OpenGL ES?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, opengl-es

For example I want to display a rectangle like a UIView and assign it a background color. Then I want to update the color and size of the rectangle. Is this hard to do? How?

Note: I need dozens of these rectangles and have to update them as often per second as possible. The performance of Quartz / UIKit / CA isn't good enough for my case.

Answer (score -1):

OpenGL would be overkill for such a trivial task. [Quartz](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [CoreGraphics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreGraphics/Reference/CoreGraphics_Framework/_index.html) is more than cable of doing this. Check out the [Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Believe me when I tell you, the performance of Quartz / CA is not good enough. I have good reasons for my question :-)

Comment: Well then I would say it should not be too terribly difficult. I would dig around some of Apple's GL examples as well as check other sites. Are you looking for 2D or 3D rectangle?

Comment: 2D would be sufficient. Whatever delivers the best updating performance when changing background color and frame...